# ios + use asynudpsocket from the app delegate

Tags: iphone, udp, asyncsocket

I have created a simple app using the AsynUDPSocket class. It listens to simple text messages from a UDP client.

When I put the relevant code into a view controller, everything works fine. But when I try the same in the app delegate my app crashes. This thing worked fine in the app delegate a few days back. Now I dont know what's wrong.

I used the code from [this post](http://cocoadev.com/forums/discussion/1642/asyncudpsocket-receiving-duplicate-udp-packet-or-so-it-seems/p1)
.Can someone please elaborate?

EDIT: Code

My App Delegate's .h file contents

```
    //
//  MacSocketTestAppDelegate.h
//  MacSocketTest
//
//  Created by core on 04/05/11.
//  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2011. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AsyncUdpSocket.h"

#import "SocketController.h"
#import "NextController.h"


@class SocketController;

@class SocketTest;

@interface MacSocketTestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;

    SocketTest *connection;

    AsyncUdpSocket *aSyncSocket;

    UIViewController *currentViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SocketController *mySC;

@property (nonatomic, retain) SocketTest *connection;

@property (nonatomic, retain) AsyncUdpSocket *aSyncSocket;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *currentViewController;

@end
```

My App Delegate's .m file contents

```
//
//  MacSocketTestAppDelegate.m
//  MacSocketTest
//
//  Created by core on 04/05/11.
//  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2011. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MacSocketTestAppDelegate.h"
#import "SocketController.h"
#import "SocketTest.h"

#import "NextController.h"

@implementation MacSocketTestAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize mySC;
@synthesize connection;

@synthesize aSyncSocket;

@synthesize currentViewController;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    aSyncSocket=[[AsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self]; //We are the delegate for the asynchronous socket object.

    [aSyncSocket bindToPort:30000 error:nil]; //We want to listen on port 30000. Don't care about errors for now.

    [aSyncSocket receiveWithTimeout:-1 tag:1]; //Start listening for a UDP packet.



    SocketTest *instanceST = [SocketTest alloc];
    [self setConnection:instanceST];

    SocketController *instanceSocketController = [[SocketController alloc] initWithNibName: @"SocketController" bundle: nil];
    [self setMySC:instanceSocketController];
    [instanceSocketController release];

    [[self window] setRootViewController:[self mySC]];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

     //Other methods hidden

#pragma mark AsyncUdpSocket Delegate Method

//This method is called by the AsyncUdpSocket object when a packet is received:
- (BOOL)onUdpSocket:(AsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag fromHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
{
    NSString *theLine=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; //Convert the UDP data to an NSString

    NSLog(@"%@", theLine);

    [theLine release];

    [aSyncSocket receiveWithTimeout:-1 tag:1]; //Listen for the next UDP packet to arrive...which will call this method again in turn.

    return YES; //Signal that we didn't ignore the packet.
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

EDIT: Crash log

```
The Debugger has exited with status 0.
[Session started at 2011-05-05 15:29:18 +0530.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1469) (Wed May  5 04:36:56 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 1706.
Pending breakpoint 1 - ""MacSocketTestAppDelegate.m":41" resolved
MacSocketTest(1706) malloc: recording malloc stacks to disk using standard recorder
MacSocketTest(1706) malloc: stack logging compaction turned off; size of log files on disk can increase rapidly
MacSocketTest(1706) malloc: process 1547 no longer exists, stack logs deleted from /tmp/stack-logs.1547.MacSocketTest.bEuUBJ.index
MacSocketTest(1706) malloc: stack logs being written into /tmp/stack-logs.1706.MacSocketTest.SJLaue.index
(gdb) continue
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
2011-05-05 15:29:46.698 MacSocketTest[1706:207] *** -[MacSocketTestAppDelegate respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5954e00
(gdb)
```

Thanks,
Angelo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with the information you're giving us I would guess you probably messed up the memory management. I guess so because that's the most common cause for crashes.

> I used the code from this post.

What post? There's no code in this post.

In order to get a decent answer that's not just based on statistical reasons for crashes you should provide code, crash log and stack trace.

**EDIT:** So you edited in the link. So now we have some code. However that code is out of context and you've already told us that it works, so we're not going to find the answer there.

**EDIT 2:**

```
2011-05-05 15:29:46.698 MacSocketTest[1706:207] *** -[MacSocketTestAppDelegate respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5954e00
```

So I was right. It was a memory issue. You're sending a message to a deallocated object. What's weird is that it seems to be your app delegate that has been deallocated.

Comment: @Angelo Could you also include the crash log?

Comment: Have edited the post to include crash logs. BTW Erik, thanks for all the help. I'm a relative newbie... and I need a hand around software. I make my grade with electronics and embedded systems.

Comment: @Angelo I edited the answer. Perhaps you could include the stack trace as well?

Comment: I have no idea how to get hold of that. Would appreciate if you can help me on this front. And, I am moving away from my app delegate to another screen and from that screen to yet another one. Hope that can provide a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Erik, your comments were spot on. I have figured out my problem's location.

Let me explain:
Like I commmented, I'm moving from the app delegate to one screen, and from that screen to another one.

In essence, in the last screen's (view's) view controller, I was creating an instance of my app delegate to set the last screen's view controller as my currentViewController property of my app delegate. I'm maintaining it for different reasons.

I was, also, DEALLOCATING, the instance of the app delegate right after I was done setting my currentViewController property. Once I removed that line, I was good and my app was up and running.

I think I should deallocate it in the dealloc method. Please correct my understanding, if I'm wrong.

Thanks a million to you, Erik, for pointing me in the right direction.

EDIT: Erik, please tell me how you knew from the crash logs, that it was my app delegate that was being deallocated it.

Angelo.